# M1 Macbook Air doesn't recognize Apple wired numeric keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb

I've tried connecting my old Apple wired numeric keyboard to my M1 mac and it's not "fully" recognized. The mac does recognize the USB hub of the keyboard and it recognizes elements attached to the hub, for example a USB mouse, but it does not recognize the Keyboard itself.

[image]
[image: periferals]

Comment: Tested with an old Extended wired keyboard on an M1 iMac still running Big Sur. It won't detect the key left of Z in the keyboard 'recogniser', but appears fully operational other than that.

Comment: Well... after leaving the keyboard connected for a full day or more(?) the keyboard is now responding... I didn't do anything special, I just left it connected and moved it out of the way while I worked on the laptop keyboard. Every once in a while I tried pressing the keys to see if it responded and now, all of a sudden, it started working, now I'm afraid of disconnecting it :)